# Is possible to add a javascript library from backend multiple time using wicket framework without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.5, wicket-1.6

I want to add a javascript library in my page each time when we click on a AjaxLink in apache wicket without refreshing the page. Is it possible to add Javascript library without refreshing the page and trigger that library each time on a function call ?

```
//Here , MetaModelPagePanel trigger and add a javascript file and create a graph using this 


RepeatingView graphTesting1= new RepeatingView("graphTesting");
MetaModelPagePanel graphTesting = new MetaModelPagePanel(graphTesting1.newChildId(), getRepositoryKey());
graphTesting1.add(graphTesting.setVisible(false));
OverViewpanel.add(graphTesting1);


AjaxLink onClickGraph_Container = new AjaxLink<>("onClickGraph_Test") {
    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

       
        MetaModelPagePanel graphTesting = new MetaModelPagePanel(graphTesting1.newChildId(), getRepositoryKey());
      
        graphTesting1.add(graphTesting);

        OverViewpanel.add(graphTesting1.setVisible(true));


    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to include the library just once and call it as many times as needed.

To include the library just add it as a dependency of any Component that is used:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
   response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(MyPanel.class, "my-library.js"));
}
```

The in your AjaxLink#onClick() just call it:

```
@Override
public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
   ...
   target.appendJavaScript("myLibrary.doSomething('"+param1+"', '"+param2+"')");
}
```

where `param1` and `param2` are just a demo of how you could pass any arguments to your function calculated for each click of the link.